# R' Built in Editor - How to keep destination formatting font when copy and pasting from a different source?

Tags: r

In R's built in editor, when I copy and paste text from another source, the font size, type, etc usually changes. This doesn't happen in RStudio, which retains the destination formatting. Hence, I usually have to copy and paste text first into a text document, then into R's built in editor. I was wondering if there was a way by default to have R convert whatever text I paste in as the default text format? Thanks.

Comment: The built-in editor in Rgui is extremely basic. That's why you have alternatives like RStudio. You can also use any 3rd party text editor: Sublime Text, VSCode, Notepad++, emacs, vi, or whatever.

Comment: Once you've pasted the varied-font text into the basic editor, save, close, then re-open, are the font properties preserved or do they revert to basic-ASCII?